# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object- NES.EventHandlerFactory

Tags: cqrs

I have written my code as follows:

```
public class ConferenceService
    {
        private static readonly IEventFactory _eventFactory = DI.Current.Resolve<IEventFactory>();
        private static readonly IEventHandlerFactory _eventHandlerFactory = DI.Current.Resolve<IEventHandlerFactory>();
        private readonly string nameOrConnectionString;
        private readonly RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy> retryPolicy;

        public ConferenceService(string nameOrConnectionString = "ConferenceManagement")
        {

            this.nameOrConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;

            this.retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)) { FastFirstRetry = true });
            this.retryPolicy.Retrying += (s, e) =>
                Trace.TraceWarning("An error occurred in attempt number {1} to access the database in ConferenceService: {0}", e.LastException.Message, e.CurrentRetryCount);

        }

        public void CreateConference(ConferenceInfo conference)
        {
            using (var context = new ConferenceContext(this.nameOrConnectionString))
            {
                var existingSlug = this.retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => 
                    context.Conferences
                        .Where(c => c.Slug == conference.Slug)
                        .Select(c => c.Slug)
                        .Any());

                if (existingSlug)
                    throw new DuplicateNameException("The chosen conference slug is already taken.");

                // Conference publishing is explicit. 
                if (conference.IsPublished)
                    conference.IsPublished = false;

                context.Conferences.Add(conference);
                this.retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => context.SaveChanges());

               this.PublishConferenceEvent<ConferenceCreated>(conference);
            }
        }


        private void PublishConferenceEvent<T>(ConferenceInfo conference)
            where T : ConferenceEvent, new()
        {

            Action<T> action = x => new T
            {
                SourceId = conference.Id,
                Owner = new Owner
                {
                    Name = conference.OwnerName,
                    Email = conference.OwnerEmail,
                },
                Name = conference.Name,
                Description = conference.Description,
                Location = conference.Location,
                Slug = conference.Slug,
                Tagline = conference.Tagline,
                TwitterSearch = conference.TwitterSearch,
                StartDate = conference.StartDate,
                EndDate = conference.EndDate,
            };

            Apply(action);
        }


        private void Apply<TEvent>(Action<TEvent> action)
        {
           var @event = _eventFactory.Create(action);
           Raise(@event);
        }

        private void Raise(object @event)
        {
            _eventHandlerFactory.Get(this, @event.GetType())(@event);
        }
    }
```

But when I run my code and try to create a conference it shows me following exception message:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 10:     public class EventHandlerFactory : IEventHandlerFactory
>   Line 11:     { Line 12:         private static readonly ILogger Logger
>   = LoggerFactory.Create(typeof(EventHandlerFactory)); Line 13:         private static readonly Dictionary>> _cache = new Dictionary>>(); Line 14:         private
>   static readonly object _cacheLock = new object();
>
> Source File:
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\src\NES\EventHandlerFactory.cs    Line:
>   12
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    NES.EventHandlerFactory..cctor() in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\src\NES\EventHandlerFactory.cs:12
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'NES.EventHandlerFactory' threw an exception.]
>   NES.EventHandlerFactory..ctor() +0    NES.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_4() in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\src\NES\DI.cs:24
>   NES.DependencyInjectionContainer.Resolve() in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\src\NES\DependencyInjectionContainer.cs:21
>   Conference.ConferenceService..cctor() in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\samples\Conference\ConferenceService.cs:23
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Conference.ConferenceService' threw an exception.]
>   Conference.ConferenceService..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString) in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\samples\Conference\ConferenceService.cs:36
>   Conference.Web.Admin.Controllers.ConferenceController.get_Service() in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\samples\Conference.Web.Admin\Controllers\ConferenceController.cs:32
>   Conference.Web.Admin.Controllers.ConferenceController.Create(ConferenceInfo
>   conference) in
>   F:\MyProjects\NES\NES-master\samples\Conference.Web.Admin\Controllers\ConferenceController.cs:119
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +486
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +71
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +85    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +82
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +143
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +109
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +121    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +321    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +143
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +109
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +76    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +184
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +81
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +73
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +47    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +81
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +49
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9644037    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: What does the constructor in EventHandlerFactory.cs look like? The error occurs on row 12 in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed. The problem raises due to configuration. Finally I fixed this issue by adding following line of code inside Application_Start() method of Global.asax.

```
LogManager.Use<NServiceBus.Log4Net.Log4NetFactory>();
```